# Minimum energy required to roll a cuboid through an angle of 90°

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, energy-conservation, potential-energy

I'm stuck on this textbook question about the minimum energy required to roll a cuboid through 90° from an upright position to a horizontal position (see image). I believe the correct answer is A, 200 J.

[image]

I really don't know which approach to use here. Even my physics teacher is stumped. I don't think I can use difference in potential energy here since I'm not lifting the box, just rolling it, so the weight cannot be 4000N in any case. I'm wondering why the value of the answer is so small. Is the principle of moments applicable here? Or is it something to do with the change in centre of gravity? Can someone give me some hints to get to the correct answer?

Comment: Hi Lim and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Comment: It should shift to the edge of the cube until it lies out of the base area and topples.

Comment: It decreases by 0.35m. However,when I calculated the change in potential energy I get C as the answer

Comment: http://giphy.com/gifs/cube-9QH5nxaP3zeBq

Comment: Based on the gif,its centre does not change,just its direction its pointing to. So must I calculate that change to get the answer?

Comment: Thanks! I've got it. So, the only work done is by raising the COM BY 0.05m is it? I never knew that the COM would be raised instead of lowered. After the edge, why there's no other work done? Is it because of gravity?

Comment: The title of this question contains almost no information. "Need help" is obvious because this is a website for people who want to get questions to answers. "physics problem" is also obvious because this is a website about physics. Please read [this meta post](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6413/how-do-we-write-good-question-titles) about how to write meaningful question titles.

Comment: Can centre of mass actually change? We are just moving it temporarily, right? Because I remember an experiment conducted in the lab showing the centre of mass to be constant, wherever you hang the load from.

Comment: i quite like this question, i don't think it ought to be closed. it is quite counterintuitive that work must be done to raise the COM

Comment: @DanielSank I've since edited the question's title. Lim, in the future, do try to make your question title more descriptive

Comment: @LimLS You cannot tilt the box without lifting it over it's own edge. Counterintuitive, yes, but that's how it is. Only a round shape can roll over without changing CoM. So, the CoM will have to be raised slightly, and this is the "energy barrier" that you must overcome. You overcome this by doing work. `After the edge, why there's no other work done?` After the edge there *is* work done, but only by gravity now, which loweres the CoM (there are no more energy barriers.) To you last comment: No, position of CoM will not change in a rigid object. Only for elastic materials or fluids or so.

Comment: You might find it instructive to draw a diagram of the potential energy of the block as a function of the angle - you will see that there are two minima (corresponding to the stable positions) with a small bump in between. The bump is the energy you have to overcome to move from one to the other.

Answer (score 1):

When you rotate the block, the center of mass (which lies midway on the diagonal) will move until the diagonal is perpendicular.  Therefore, the center of mass must rise from the midpoint of the vertical edge of the block to the midpoint of the (now vertical) diagonal.

If you push horizontally on the top edge of the block, you've got a lever equal to the diagonal of the block pivoting on the fulcrum of the edge on which the block rolls.  But this will not affect the energy required to roll the block.

Comment: Nah, it's just a  cie a level physics question.

Comment: work done will be same, even using levers or ropes and ladders